# How to prevent Google Voice incoming calls from vibrating my phone?

Tags: calls, android-10, vibration, google-voice

How can I configure Google Voice so that when I receive a call my phone from Google Voice, the phone doesn't vibrate?

I configured Google Voice to forward call to my phone. However, even when the phone on silent mode (no sound, no vibration), the phone vibrates.

How can I configure Google Voice so that when I receive a call my phone from Google Voice, the phone doesn't vibrate? I want it to stay 100% silent.

I use Samsung Galaxy S9 (non-rooted Android 10, One UI 2.0).